# Can any body please explain this line of code in operator overloading for the plus

Tags: c++

The code below is being used to add two complex numbers using operator overloading but I do not understand the argument and the body of the plus operator. Can anyone please explain this?

```
complex operator+(complex a2) // why this argument is used please explain 
{  
    complex a;  //what is the need of this
    a.r=r+a2.r;  //and how it is being done 
    a.i=i+a2.i;  //this one too
    return a;  
}
```

I understand that complex is a class and a is its object but i am in illusion why then we used the a2.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)? That should cover more than everything you need to answer the question.

Comment: If you're adding two numbers, you need two numbers. `a2` is the second number and the insance of the class is the first. `a = a1 + a2;`

Comment: i want a simple explanation of my code very simple..

Comment: Thanks i got it.. a little bit more is expected to explain me the a object

Comment: @Paramour Why can't you read the linked questions yourself? People must do serious research before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
complex operator+(complex a2) // why this argument is used please explain 
{  
   complex a;  //what is the need of this
   a.r=r+a2.r;  //and how it is being done 
   a.i=i+a2.i;  //this one too
   return a;   
 }
```

Your question is "I do not understand the argument and the body of the plus operator" and "I understand that complex is a class and a is its object but i am in illusion why then we used the a2."

Think about if you don't pass `complex a2` object as a parameter when you are defining the overloaded function like this `complex operator+()` it will produce an error message because it has required one parameter.

When you will create the object of `complex` class in main function `complex a2` provide help you to pass the value of any other object for sum operation.

Here is a demo.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class N{
private:
    int x,y;
public:
    N(int a=0,int b=0)
    {
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    void print(){
        cout<<x<<" : "<<y<<endl;
    }
    N operator+(N a)
    {
        x=a.x;
    }
};
int main(){
    N b;
    N a(2,3);
   a.print();
   b.print();
   b.operator+(a);
   b.print();
   return 0;
 }
```

Hope you have got the idea about `complex a2` argument. If not comment below.

Answer (score 1):

The operator in the question deals with the situation when two `complex` objects are added together to form a new *temporary* value:

```
a1 + a2
```

When the compiler sees that expression it creates a third (temporary) value which is their sum.

It does this by treating the `+` as a member function of the *left hand side* of the expression. So the above code is equivalent to this:

```
a1.operator+(a2); // member function call
```

So the *body* of your function is the body of a member function for object `a1`:

```
complex operator+(complex a2) // member function of a1 receiving a2 as a parameter 
{  
    complex a;       // this is the new value that will be created from a1 + a2
    a.r = r + a2.r;  // r is a1.r because this object is a1 
    a.i = i + a2.i;  // same with i

    return a;        // the (temporary) result is returned
}
```

The *temporary* result is only used if it is assigned to a named variable like this:

```
a = a1 + a2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading generally means that you can do something more than what that operator generally does.
Here you are adding two complex numbers using "+" operator overloading.So you are doing some thing like this.

result = a1+ a2 where a1 and a2 are two complex numbers
 with a real and imaginary part respectively.
Consider +operator as function name so how will you pass a parameter to the function. a2 is the another number that you want to add with a1 so a2 goes in as a parameter which is also of complex type, and the function return a complex object as "a" which includes real and imaginary part.
I hope I answer what you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

```
complex operator+(complex a2) // why this argument is used please explain 
{  
    complex a;  //what is the need of this
    a.r=r+a2.r;  //and how it is being done 
    a.i=i+a2.i;  //this one too
    return a;  
}
```

Ans 1. `complex operator+(complex a2)`
The `complex` is specifying that the return type is going to be of the `type class complex`. `complex a2` specifies that the operator is going to be used with an object of `class complex`.

Ans 2. `complex a;` This is required to do a temporary operation with the objects and data members of the class complex. Think of it like a `temp` variable you introduces to add 2 numbers in a function and return it later on.

Ans 3. `a.r=r+a2.r;` Okay now that you have cheated a temporary object of the class complex you say *storing the sum of `a2`'s `r` and the the **object that called this overloading function's** `r`* and storing it into the temporary object's `r`.

Ans 4. `a.i=i+a2.i;` Same as above.

Then you `return` the temporary object `a` with the calculated sums of `r` and `i`. Note that the `type` of `a` is of the `class complex` and so the return type was specified as `complex` in line 1.

You will understand it better if you also see the operator being used in the `main()` function.

```
complex x,y,z;
x=y+z;
```

Here `x` will get the value of the temporary object `a`. The calling variable is `y` and `a2` will receive `z`. It is like calling `+` here like
 `x = y.overloaded_plus(z) // only for explanation`

Comment: Thanks for all the kind answers.

Comment: @Paramour Consider up-voting an answer if it helped (by hitting the up-arrow symbol) and mark it accepted by clicking the *tick* symbol next to the answer. This is to keep the author's spirit high and for some recognition